Why is my flask app not working on windows?
So i created a Flask app and it worked perferctly on ubuntu, but on windows i get this error: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'uploads\my_paswords.json'
here is the code of the app:
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for, session, send_from_directory, after_this_request
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
import json
import getpass
import os


def derive_key(master_password, salt):
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=300000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    return urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(master_password.encode()))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'fb94adeeae03fc053356cf617741eabb'
upload_folder= 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']= upload_folder
if not os.path.exists(upload_folder):
    os.makedirs(upload_folder)
#index
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/redirect_lc', methods=['POST'])
def hanle_redirect_lc():
    action = request.form.get('action')
    if action == 'load':
        return redirect(url_for('load_database'))
    elif action == 'create':
        return redirect(url_for('create_db'))
#/index

#create
@app.route('/create_db')
def create_db():
    return render_template('create.html')
@app.route('/redirect_cr', methods=['POST'])
def handle_redirect_cr():
    session['db_name'] = f"{request.form.get('database_name')}.json"
    session['master_password'] = request.form.get('master_password')
    return render_template('first_entry.html')

@app.route('/create_db', methods=['POST'])
def handle_create_db():
    platform = request.form.get('platform')
    user = request.form.get('user')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    salt = os.urandom(16)
    session['key'] = derive_key(session.get('master_password'), salt)
    session['filepath'] = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f"{session.get('db_name')}")
    with open(session.get('filepath'), 'w') as f:
        json.dump({'salt': salt.hex(), 'platforms': {platform: {'user': user, 'password': Fernet(session.get('key')).encrypt(password.encode()).decode()}}}, f, indent=4)
    with open(session.get('filepath'), 'r') as f:
        session['data'] = json.load(f)
    return render_template('platforms.html', data= session.get('data'), Fernet=Fernet, key = session.get('key'))

#/create


#load
@app.route('/load_database')
def load_database():
    return render_template('load.html')
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    master_password = request.form.get('master_password')
    if file and file.filename.endswith('.json'):
        session['filepath']= os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename)
        file.save(session.get('filepath'))
        session['db_name']=file.filename
        session['master_password'] = master_password
        with open(session.get('filepath'), 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            session['data']= data
            salt = data['salt']
            temp_dict = next(iter(data['platforms'].items()))
            temp_dict = temp_dict[1]
            key = derive_key(session.get('master_password'), bytes.fromhex(salt))
            session['key']= key
            try:
                Fernet(key).decrypt(temp_dict['password'])
                return render_template('platforms.html', data = data, key = key, Fernet=Fernet)
            except:
                @after_this_request
                def remove_db(response):
                    os.remove(session.get('filepath'))
                    return response
                return f"wrong password"
    else:
        return "wrong file type!"

#/load

#platforms
@app.route("/redirect", methods=['POST'])
def redirect_action():
    action = request.form.get('action')
    if action == 'add':
        return render_template('add_entry.html')
    if action == 'save':
        return redirect(url_for('save_page'))
@app.route('/add_db', methods=['POST'])
def handle_add_db():
    platform = request.form.get('platform')
    user = request.form.get('user')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    with open(session.get('filepath'), 'r+') as f:
        session['data'] = json.load(f)
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        session.get('data')['platforms'][platform] = {'user': user, 'password': Fernet(session.get('key')).encrypt(password.encode()).decode()}
        json.dump(session.get('data'), f, indent=4)
    return render_template('platforms.html', data=session.get('data'), Fernet=Fernet, key=session.get('key'))

@app.route('/delete/<platform>')
def delete(platform):
    with open(session.get('filepath'), 'r+') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        del data['platforms'][platform]
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
        return render_template('platforms.html', data = data, key = session.get('key'), Fernet=Fernet)

@app.route('/save_page')
def save_page():
    return render_template('saved.html')

@app.route('/save')
def save():
    @after_this_request
    def remove_db(response):
        os.remove(session.get('filepath'))
        return response

    if os.path.exists(session.get('filepath')):
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f"{session.get('db_name')}", as_attachment=True)
    else:
        return "File not found", 404


#/platforms


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,use_reloader=False)

checked if the file was open somewhere, doesnt seem like it is beacuse i always used "with open()" and it should be closed automatically

maybe also check the Task Manager can search for my_paswords.json check if the file is open in another app, e.g. text editor, etc.

try making a copy and open that ... does it succeed ?

@chickitychinachinesechicken , can`t see anything in task manager about the json file.
@ticktalk make a copy with ctrl+c and ctrl+v? that works and i can copy  and open it, just can`t delete it from the flask app with os.remove.... but i can remove it with left click + delete in file explorer

Saving the uploaded file using the file name specified in the upload request is a very bad security mistake. Usually this ends up in a path traversal vulnerability and remote code execution. Therefore always generate a temp file name you save the data to. This also avoids conflicts where ,multiple users upload a file of the same name at the same time.
